# Python and JS [object HTMLSelectElement] and [object HTMLInputElement] declaration issues

Tags: javascript, python, html

This is my python code that I need to use to write the data I get into a seperate .txt file that saves it and it's possible to open it anytime and watch, what's inside

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import cgi, cgitb,sys,string

    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print
    print("tere")

    formdata = cgi.FieldStorage()

    scorefile="results.txt"

    size=""
    bombs=""
    moves=""
    name="" 
    if formdata.has_key("ruudud"):
        ruudud=formdata['ruudud'].value
    if formdata.has_key("pommid"):
        pommid=formdata['pommid'].value
    if formdata.has_key("moves"):
        moves=formdata['moves'].value
    if formdata.has_key("name"):
        name=formdata['name'].value


    f=open(scorefile,"a")
    f.write(name+"\n")
    f.write("Ruutude arv: "+size+"\n")
    f.write("Pommide arv: "+bombs+"\n")
    f.write("Käikude arv: "+moves+"\n")
    f.close()
```

and here's some JS code I have

```
var board;
var games = 0;
var moves = 0;
var bombs;
var gameOver = false;
var dim;

function startGame() {
    gameOver = false;
    var e = document.getElementById("ruudud");
    dim = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    var nrOfBombs = document.getElementById("pommid").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

And this is the output in results.txt [link](https://gyazo.com/778f84ee7e212f8bedd032cec8b3fca2)
What do I need to declare or have I declared something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use formdata to pass values on the client side, if so:

Getting `[object HTMLInputElement]` back as string it means you've passed the object and not its value. use `element.value` in the HTML when submitting values.